# Is there a way to determine which coefficient of $an^2 - 1$ yields the most prime numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-mathematics

I was wondering - is there a way to determine which coefficient $a$ yields the most primes in this expression: $$a \cdot n^2 -1$$  where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and it goes from $[\alpha , \beta] ~~ \alpha, \beta > 0, ~\beta > \alpha$

I tried to program a code which gets the range we want to check for $n$, $[0,1000]$ and the coefficients between $[1,1000]$ and got to the solution of $a=398$ which yields about $40.14\%$ primes.
Is there any way to determine this? It sounds interesting.

Thank you.

Comment: well, I would say that the set of primes is of density zero among the primes. In contrast,  when $a > 0$ is not a square, $f(x,y) = a x^2 - y^2$  represents a positive fraction of all primes.

Comment: I'm impressed: up to 1,000,000 some 200,000 primes, here is the end 999992    prime   397993632025471 count:  234137
progress  1000000

Sun May 31 18:08:31 PDT 2020

Comment: I guess that is enough. Up to 10,000,000   about 20% of values are prime 9999997    prime   39799976120003581 count:  2039778
10000000    prime   39799999999999999 count:  2039779

Sun May 31 18:26:18 PDT 2020

Comment: There is no shortcut, you have to try all the possibilities for $a$. Some $a$ can be detected to be bad for generating primes before, in particular perfect squares, but the champion cannot be determined efficiently.

Comment: You can probably calculate the solution a=398 via some modular arithmetic calculations. For example the best solution all are divisible by 2, just like 398.

Comment: Why even numbers are generally better can be explained easily. If a is even $a\times n^2-1$ is always odd and therefore possibly prime. if a is odd, $a\times n^2-1$ is even for odd n and therefore definitly composite for half the values.